# Create commands in terminal for executing own program and its commands

Tags: terminal

I was wondering how to configure a program (for example written in Python) so i can run it from the terminal (Ubuntu) and its commands, without using an alias.
For example:

$myprogram dosomething

and that should execute the code which refers to dosomething

Thank you very much!

Comment: What kind of terminal are you using? (i.e. dos, bash...)

Comment: sorry my bad, already fixed the post, its for ubuntu and python @tanjir

Comment: Even ubuntu supports different shells (bash, tcsh, ksh and so on).. I am assuming you are using bash. You can write a shell script that will run the python script with your input and put the script in /usr/local/bin you can start terminal and can use that command.. (make sure to chmod to +x)